# opa gatekeeper detects but doesn't denies

Tags: kubernetes, opa-gatekeeper

OPA gateekeeper doesn't enforces policy.

I have installed the policy from https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/blob/master/library/general/disallowedrepos/template.yaml and applied the constraint https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/blob/master/library/general/disallowedrepos/samples/repo-must-not-be-k8s-gcr-io/constraint.yaml

the problem I'm facing is that gatekeeper detects the violation and writes to the log but doesn't denies the creation of the resource. I can still create a pod with wrong registry name.

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kustomize-disallowed
spec:
  containers:
    - name: kustomize
      image: k8s.gcr.io/kustomize/kustomize:v3.8.9
```

**Log file**

```
{"level":"info","ts":1705611801.8987546,"logger":"controller",
"msg":"container <kustomize> has an invalid image repo <k8s.gcr.io/kustomize/kustomize:latest>,
 disallowed repos are [\"k8s.gcr.io/\"]",
"process":"audit","audit_id":"2024-01-18T21:03:20Z",
"details":{},"event_type":"violation_audited",
"constraint_group":"constraints.gatekeeper.sh",
"constraint_api_version":"v1beta1","constraint_kind":"K8sDisallowedRepos",
"constraint_name":"repo-must-not-be-k8s-gcr-io","constraint_namespace":"",
"constraint_action":"deny","constraint_annotations":{},"resource_group":"","resource_api_version":"v1",
"resource_kind":"Pod","resource_namespace":"default",
"resource_name":"kustomize-disallowed","resource_labels":null}
```

I installed gatekeeper using this command

```
kubectl apply -f  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper/release-3.14/deploy/gatekeeper.yaml
```

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
gatekeeper-audit-7fb7b5997c-ksqlv               1/1     Running   1 (44m ago)   44m
gatekeeper-controller-manager-9b69bcf5d-7cxdw   1/1     Running   0             44m
gatekeeper-controller-manager-9b69bcf5d-d94kc   1/1     Running   0             44m
gatekeeper-controller-manager-9b69bcf5d-lgwd5   1/1     Running   0             44m
```